# angular form validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-validation-engine

I have this simple form with a text box that is required and a save button.

```
<form role="form" name="frmVariableConfig" novalidate ng-submit="frmVariableConfig.$valid && vm.saveChanges()">                
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.CurrCustomer.Name" name="txtCustomerName" class="form-control input-sm validate[required]" placeholder="txtCustomerName" check-validation>   
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm text-right">Save</button>                
</form>
```

I'm using this directive to activate the Jquery Validation Engine

```
angular.module('app').directive('checkValidation', [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: '?ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                element.closest('form').validationEngine(
                    {
                        promptPosition: 'centerRight',
                        scroll: true, prettySelect: true,
                        autoPositionUpdate: true,
                        //validateNonVisibleFields: true,
                        //autoHidePrompt: true,
                        autoHideDelay: 1000,
                        fadeDuration: 0.9
                    }
                );
            }
        };
    }]);
```

but it keeps on calling saveChanges() even if the text-box is empty. It should not call this function if the text-box is empty.

Please help.

Comment: Have you considered using [Angular Validation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)?

Comment: gave up and now using angular validation :) my drop down is a bootstrap-select which has some hidden stuff going on that required validation . so now the behaviour is fine but i get An invalid form control with name=xxx is not focusable." error on save.

Comment: actually its not related to this question. but rest of the stuff is working. except this.

Answer (score 0):

In one project, the only way I found to solve this scenario was to pass the value of $valid to save method.

HTML

```
ng-submit="vm.saveChanges( frmVariableConfig.$valid )"
```

JS

```
$scope.saveChanges = function(valid) {  
  if(valid) {
    //do save  
  }
}
```